# Drupal 7 theme Template.php Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR error

Tags: php, drupal-7, php-5.6, drupal-themes

I'm new to Drupal development and trying to run a preprocess function for a content type inside my custom theme's `template.php`.

Here's my code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_article(&$variables) {
  if (!field_image_alt_text->getValue().strlen() = 0 || null ) { set value to something }else {return;}
};
```

but it returns a syntax error as:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

How can I . resolve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not php syntax and is missing from some information ,  where field_image_alt_text provide ? .. make no sens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u dont resolve this, code not php language

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_article(&$variables) {
  if (strlen(field_image_alt_text->getValue()) = 0 || null ) { set value to something }else {return;}
};
```

Comment: I have tried this: `function laurel2015_preprocess_article(&$variables) {
  if (strlen(field_image_alt_text->getValue()) = 0 || null ) { set 'laurel_image'; }else {return;}
};` but it says: `syntax error UNEXPECTED T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ')'`